# How to debug M2 Macbook Air screen going black right after unlocking

Tags: bug, unlock, screen-lock

First of the hardware/software involved here:

- 2023 15” MacBook Air M2
- 16GB RAM
- Sonoma 14.4

Randomly, but rather frequently, right after unlocking my Mac with Touch ID my screen go black and unresponsive. The only fix I have found so far is to physically close the laptop, reopen it and unlock it again (to be clear: there's no need for a reboot).

This is a minor, but recurring, inconvenience and I'm a bit at a loss on how to troubleshoot it. The logs clearly show the first unlock followed by the close laptop/second unlock:

```
$ log show --predicate '(eventMessage CONTAINS "lockUIPresentedWithoutSuccessfulUnlock = NO")' --style syslog --last 1h
Filtering the log data using "composedMessage CONTAINS "lockUIPresentedWithoutSuccessfulUnlock = NO""
Skipping info and debug messages, pass --info and/or --debug to include.
Timestamp                       (process)[PID]
2024-03-11 17:51:50.195153+0000  localhost loginwindow[544]: [com.apple.loginwindow.logging:Standard] -[LWScreenLock handleUnlockResult:]_block_invoke |      _lockUIPresentedWithoutSuccessfulUnlock = NO
2024-03-11 17:51:54.912174+0000  localhost loginwindow[544]: [com.apple.loginwindow.logging:Standard] -[LWScreenLock handleUnlockResult:]_block_invoke |      _lockUIPresentedWithoutSuccessfulUnlock = NO
```

Which logs between those two timestamps should I be looking at to debug this further. I fully appreciate this might be an issue with the hardware, or MacOS itself but equally it could be a user error (or maybe due to some software I installed), either way, I'm looking for direction on how to narrow down the behavior I'm seeing (even if that's only being able to repro it consistently).

Edit:

Running `pmset displaysleepnow` a few times in a row make it easier to repro, it's still not consistent but it speeds up the lock/unlock/repro cycle. Will attempt safe mode.

Edit 2:

I know have a *consistent* repro, that also repros in safe mode:

1. Run `pmset displaysleepnow` from a shell
2. **Quickly** use Touch ID as soon as the screen goes to sleep
3. The screen is now black/unusable, and requires the laptop to be closed/open

Comment: On a less-than-one-year-old Mac, I would take it to an Apple Store to determine if it's a hardware fault. In many countries, you should be within your statutory rights for a refund or replacement for defective hardware.

Comment: I would test in safe mode. If the problem can't be reproduced, it's caused by third-party software.

Comment: Thanks @LincD, see my 2nd edit if you're curious. I know have a consistent repro. I guess the next step will be to see if that's specific to my Macbook or can be reproed on any.

Comment: I have a 13" M2 MBA, and it doesn't do that. Yours seems to be defective, or maybe it's connected to a defective peripheral.

Comment: Why did you roll back the edit?  “Hardware” is spelled wrong and putting specifications as an image means it’s not indexable by search engines.

Comment: @Allan it wasn't rolled back? https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/470956/revisions doesn't show it being rolled back either (it does however show edits being made within seconds of each other)

Comment: That’s so weird.   Glad it’s sorted, though.